What is the difference between Eventual Consistency, Strong Eventual Consistency, and Causal Consistency?
I read articles about CRDTs and frequently come across the terms 'Strong Eventual Consistency,' 'Eventual Consistency,' and 'Causal Consistency.' What is the relationship between these consistency criteria? Which ones include the others, and which is the strongest?

Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Can you [edit] your question to describe what you think these terms mean, and how you believe they are linked? This helps us pinpoint an answer. I doubt any of us simply rehashing what you've already read will give you any more insight.

In my opinion, if you can include the information I asked about, this is a perfectly fine question for this community. In fact, I would up-vote it.

From Approaches to Conflict-free Replicated Data Types by Paulo Sérgio Almeida and Principles of Eventual Consistency by Sebastian Burckhardt:
Strong Eventual  Consistency (SEC) is  the  consistency  criterion with the following properties:

Eventual  delivery. An  update  delivered  at  some correct  replica  is  eventually  delivered  to  all  correct replicas.
Termination. All method executions terminate.
Strong  Convergence. Correct  replicas  that  have delivered  the  same  set  of  updates  have  equivalent state.

Causal Consistency is  the  consistency  criterion allowing processes to see different orders, as long as they are consistent with a global “happens-before” partial order.
